FusedLocationProviderClient keeps returning the same location if PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY is used; works normally with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
I am working on an app that tracks the user's location, and measures the total distance traveled by the user from the moment the location starts being tracked. My app has a switch that, when checked, switches to using GPS for tracking your device (and uses the PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY setting), but if unchecked, it should just use cellular networks and WiFi for location tracking (PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY).
The app works just fine in "high accuracy" mode. However, when I try to swap to the "balanced power" mode, locationResult.getLastLocation(); keeps returning the same value in every iteration. I don't understand why is this happening and I've been unable to find any explanations as to why. If possible, I would like to avoid having to rewrite the entire app from scratch with LocationManager.
I have given both the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions, and in the app settings on the device itself I can see that both permissions have been granted. I have seen a question very similar to mine here, but it hasn't been answered nor has it received any feedback, and the poster of said question had one thing in common with me: we both use Samsung devices. Could it be related to that?
Here is the code:
//LocationRequest properties
locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, 1000 * DEFAULT_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
locationRequest.setIntervalMillis(1000 * DEFAULT_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
locationRequest.setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(1000 * FAST_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
locationRequest.build();


locationCallBack = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

        //save location
        prevLocation = currLocation;
        currLocation = Objects.requireNonNull(locationResult.getLastLocation());
        updateUIValues(Objects.requireNonNull(locationResult.getLastLocation()));


    }
};


sw_gps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (sw_gps.isChecked()) {
            //most accurate - use gps sensor
            locationRequest.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            isSensorSwitchChecked = true;
            tv_sensor.setText("Using GPS sensors");
        }

        else {
            locationRequest.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            isSensorSwitchChecked = false;
            tv_sensor.setText("Using WIFI and Cell Tower signal");
        }
    }
});

Here is also the method which starts the location updates, which is called upon pressing a toggle button:
private void startLocationUpdates() {
    //tv_updates.setText("Location is being tracked");

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest.build(), locationCallBack, null);
    //totalDistance = 0.0F;
    updateGPS();
}

And finally, the updateGPS(); method, which is only called once upon startup and then any time the location starts being tracked again (tracking is unpaused). If location returns null I decided to manually set it to fixed values as to not crash the app, just in case.
private void updateGPS() {
    //get permissions for tracking GPS
    //get current location from fused client
    //update UI
    

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);


    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //user provided permission
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                //place values for location

                    if (location == null) {
                        Location startuplocation = new Location("dummyprovider");
                        startuplocation.setLongitude(0.0);
                        startuplocation.setLatitude(0.0);
                        startuplocation.setAltitude(0.0);
                        startuplocation.setAccuracy(0.0f);


                        updateUIValues(startuplocation);
                }
                else    updateUIValues(location);

            }
        });
    }
    else {
        //no perms yet
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_FINE_LOCATION);

            }

        }
    }


When using PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY it mostly uses wifi and cell towers.
